# Has Russia shown any indication, before the war, that it would court-martial its soldiers if they commit war crimes?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, war-crime, military-law

There is a number of reports of claims of Russian soldiers committing war crimes during the prosecution of Russia's 2022 war of aggression on Ukraine.

Usually armies prevent their own soldiers from committing war crimes by having clear rules of engagement which forbid them.  Such prohibitions are only credible if they are enforced through some sort of military adjudications.

Has Russia made it clear that its soldiers committing war crimes in Ukraine would be punished for them in some way?  Or has it stayed silent on the subject, or even indicated that it would sanction, or even order, committing war crimes under some circumstances?

Comment: I suppose that Russia is a part of many international agreements that require prosecuting war crimes - although, like US, it probably has reservations about allowing its citizens to be prosecuted abroad. See this one, for example: [America’s ICC Animus Gets Tested by Putin’s Alleged War Crimes](https://foreignpolicy.com/2022/03/15/us-icc-russia-invasion/)

Comment: Are you speaking in general terms - i.e. what does Russia's criminal code/military doctrine etc. say about individual responsibility for war crimes, or are you looking for specific recent statements regarding actions in Ukraine in particular?

Comment: @CDJB I would think the best way to answer this question would be to look at precedents from Russia's previous military campaigns: were war crimes committed and, if so, was anyone punished? Do you think that'd be on-topic?

Comment: @CDJB something that would indicate that these soldiers are doing it despite their orders rather than because of them.

Comment: @RogerVadim US is only against ICC targeting US soldiers and soldiers of allied countries.  Russia is not an allied country.

Comment: @divibisan yeah, I guess that could be another way to answer the question - I think the question itself is on-topic regardless.

Comment: @wrod I didn't say that US is against targeting Russian soldiers. What I meant is that Russia, like US, is not a signatory of ICC.

Comment: @RogerVadim my issue was with the title of the article you linked rather than your comment.  But, to be honest, I am not sure why the comment is relevant, either.  Russia could, in theory, be against war crimes despite not being supportive of ICC.  Certainly that's the the US position.  US just happens to trust the competency of its own courts much more.

Comment: I don't think any army has explicit rules against commiting war crimes. Armies tend to have a very detailed and explicit code of conduct that explains what soldiers are and aren't supposed to do and any possible war crime will break a number of these rules. But the army would prosecute any possible war crime through their own laws and regulations not as a war crime.

Comment: @wrod doesn't the fact that Russia denies there even is a conflict to its own citizen kind of preclude it making statements about war crimes committed in a place where there is no conflict occurring?

Comment: @CGCampbell I guess... if you could expect consistency.  But can you expect consistency from a country which declares a war (as Putin did in a 1-hour TV speech), starts it, and then claims that there is no war?

Comment: @CGCampbell: FYI, Yeltsin had declared the 1st Chechen war to be a peacekeeping mission. So there's some precedent to what's going on now. Except the press wasn't nearly as censored back then, so Yeltsin 
 was fairly ridiculed for that.

Answer (score 6):

After the Second Chechen War, Russia did prosecute a number of soldiers[1,2,3]. Some of the trials were widely-publicized and their outcomes sparked outcries.

During his stay in Slavyansk in 2014, the militia led by Strelkov did reportedly court-martial some of its soldiers for war crimes such as looting.

So tl;dr likely yes, but probably in characteristic Russian Federation fashion of "punishing the innocent and decorating the unrelated".

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arakcheev_and_Khudyakov_case
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_of_Elza_Kungayeva
3. [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ульман,_Эдуард_Анатольевич#Судебные_процессы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87#%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B)